# C and T Symmetry of Free Dirac Lagrangian

Tags: dirac-equation, time-reversal-symmetry, dirac-matrices, cpt-symmetry, charge-conjugation

I want to show the $C$ and $T$ symmetry of the free Dirac Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L}=\overline{\psi}\left(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m\right)\psi.$$

Following the notation of *Peskin, Schroeder*, we have the following relations:
$$C\psi C=-i\left(\overline{\psi}\gamma^0\gamma^2\right)^T,\\
C\overline{\psi} C=-i\left(\gamma^0\gamma^2\psi\right)^T,\\
C\gamma^\mu C=-(\gamma^\mu)^T,\\
T\psi(t,\vec{x})T=\gamma^1\gamma^3\psi(-t,\vec{x}),\\
T\overline{\psi}(t,\vec{x})T=-\overline{\psi}(-t,\vec{x})\gamma^1\gamma^3,\\
T\partial_0T=-\partial_0.$$

We have:
$$Cm\overline{\psi}\psi C
=mC\overline{\psi}CC\psi C
=-m\left(\gamma^0\gamma^2\psi\right)^T\left(\overline{\psi}\gamma^0\gamma^2\right)^T
=-m\left(\overline{\psi}\gamma^0\gamma^2\gamma^0\gamma^2\psi\right)^T\\
=m\left(\overline{\psi}\gamma^2\gamma^0\gamma^0\gamma^2\psi\right)^T
=m\left(\overline{\psi}\gamma^2\gamma^2\psi\right)^T
=-m\left(\overline{\psi}\psi\right)^T=-m\overline{\psi}\psi.$$

Here, the minus sign bothers me. But I have already checked several times.

Now for the trickier part:
$$iC\overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi C
=iC\overline{\psi}CC\gamma^\mu C\partial_\mu C\psi C
=i(-i)^2\left(\gamma^0\gamma^2\psi\right)^T(-1)(\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu)^T\left(\overline{\psi}\gamma^0\gamma^2\right)^T\\
=i\left(\overline{\psi}\gamma^0\gamma^2\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\gamma^0\gamma^2\psi\right)^T.$$

We must get rid off the $\gamma^0\gamma^2$:
$$\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\gamma^0\gamma^2
=(\gamma^0\partial_0-\gamma^1\partial_1-\gamma^2\partial_2-\gamma^3\partial_3)\gamma^0\gamma^2 \\
=\gamma^0\gamma^2(-\gamma^0\partial_0-\gamma^1\partial_1+\gamma^2\partial_2-\gamma^3\partial_3).$$

So, this is obviously where I don't know any further.

For time parity and using $\varphi(t,\vec{x}):=\psi(-t,\vec{x})$ we have:
$$mT\overline{\psi}\psi T
=-m\overline{\varphi}\gamma^1\gamma^3\gamma^1\gamma^3\varphi
=m\overline{\varphi}\gamma^3\gamma^1\gamma^1\gamma^3\varphi
=-m\overline{\varphi}\gamma^3\gamma^3\varphi
=m\overline{\varphi}\varphi.$$

And the first term is again the cumbersome one:
$$iT\overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi T
=iT\overline{\psi}TT\gamma^\mu TT\partial_\mu TT\psi T
=-i\overline{\varphi}\gamma^1\gamma^3\gamma^\mu T\partial_\mu T\gamma^1\gamma^3\varphi.$$

And yet again, the trouble lies here:
$$\gamma^\mu T\partial_\mu T\gamma^1\gamma^3
=(-\gamma^0\partial_0-\gamma^1\partial_1-\gamma^2\partial_2-\gamma^3\partial_3)\gamma^1\gamma^3 \\
=\gamma^1\gamma^3(-\gamma^0\partial_0+\gamma^1\partial_1-\gamma^2\partial_2+\gamma^3\partial_3).$$

Can somebody please tell me where I have made mistakes? I have already checked several times and have not found anything.

Comment: It is much more instructive to verify that t->-t done on the Dirac equation followed by some field transformation can bring the equation back to the original form. That field transformation is T, and only by doing that you will be sure that it is the time inversion. The lagrangian is invariant, thats is nice, but it is not really the crucial thing for understanding what T (and C, and P) is.

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign that's bothering you in the mass term is compensated by the one coming from fermion anticommutation, which you forgot to include.

$$\{\bar{\psi},\psi\}=0$$

As for the kinetic terms, you can commute the derivative $\partial_\mu$ past the gamma matrices (they're constant), leaving you with something like $\gamma^0\gamma^2\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^0\gamma^2$, which you can work out using the Clifford algebra:

$$\{\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\}=2g^{\mu\nu}$$

The RHS is also important there; it looks like it's not included in your calculations.